# How to pass a device path to an ipython profile startup script?

Tags: ipython

I'm looking for a way to pass the path of a USB/serial device to my ipython profile startup file on OS X. Because the device file can have an awkward name it would be nice if I could leverage bash completion. Something like:

`$ ipython --profile test /dev/tty.usb[TAB]`

I could then make this in to an alias `ipython-test /dev/tty.usb[TAB]'.

I'd like to do this to allow my startup script to establish a connection with some hardware.

Other ideas welcome of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by evaluating a bash command there which will give you this autocompletion effect. E.g. with tab you'd like to get the first matching entry, here's a code which will do that for you:

```
ipython --profile test `ls /dev/tty | head -n1`
```

For understanding how that works see [Understanding backticks in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48392/understanding-backtick).